# Why do I have a crease in my model?

Tags: modeling

I am new to Blender, and I can't make my mug nice and even. This happened, and I don't know how to fix it:

[image][image]

Comment: you have internal faces there. in wireframe view go looking for all the faces that should not be there and delete them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have diagonal edges coming down from the top and entering the mesh. I wouldn't be surprised if that was the origin of your problem.

Comment: How do i fix it?

Comment: Oh nevermind i just fixed it lol, thanks for your help! It took just a few seconds of thinking xD